# Linq group by and take the count

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table data:

[image: table data]

The above table data insertion works like this :- 
We have two status now (1, 2).
When an entry is created, it is having status as 1 and it is assigned to user with id 1.
When the data is updated, it will have the status as 2, and it may be be assigned to multiple user, here it is assigned to users 2 and 3.

I want the data to be grouped by the status, in the following way :-

[image: Result]

Each id should only be contained only under a single status, and that should be taken based on the latest date for each status update.
How is this possible in linq c#?

**Edit**
The following is what I could attain.

```
var result = (from el in this.logRepository.GetQuery(null)
                    group el by el.statusinto grp
                    select new
                    { ID = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()}).ToList();
```

Comment: So You basically wants to take all last entry for each user, group it by status and count users in each status. Right?

Comment: definitely **possible**, and you should try yourself first

Comment: could you please show us little code?

Comment: it's possible with the use of [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Tatranskymedved yes
@ Lei Yang, @ Nuri YILMAZ I'm sorry. I missed to post what I tried. The question is updated. I couldn't find a way to get unique ids

Comment: and what exactly is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the unique ids after doing group by

Comment: please correct your statement  adding space to statusinto like statusinto -> status into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement

> Each id should only be contained only under a single status, and that should be taken based on the latest date for each status update

you need first to group by `Id`, take the element with latest date from each grouping, and then group the result by `Status`:

```
var query =
    from e in (from e in this.logRepository.GetQuery(null)
               group e by e.Id into g
               select g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date).FirstOrDefault())
    group e by e.Status into g
    select new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

or alternatively

```
var query =
    from e in this.logRepository.GetQuery(null)
    group e by e.Id into g
    from e in g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date).Take(1)
    group e by e.Status into g
    select new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GroupBy` method to get the functionality you want.

`GroupBy(foo => foo.Bar)` results in a Dictionary where the key is the value from `foo.Bar`, and the value for each entry in the dictionary is a collection of whatever matched on the `foo.Bar` value.